# Return different list types C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to figure out how to return different list types.

Trying something like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
public Dictionary<string,object> Data;

public List<T> ReturnList(string key){  
    var type = Data[key].GetType().Name;
    switch(type){
        case "Bool":            
            return new List<bool>(); break;
        case "Int":         
            return new List<int>(); break;
        case "String": 
        case default:
            return new List<string>(); break;
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Anyone know how this is possible?

NOTE: I'm new to C#

Comment: That's not how generics work, the compile-time type needs to be known and consistent.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to return different list types for each column of data from a database.  Writing my own Query function because the WebMatrix query function (that uses IEnumerable<dynamic> and already does something like this) doesn't support async/await.

Comment: You can *use* the type of T and with a cast can "guarantee" it is type-valid to the caller (fsvo), which *supplies* the T.

Comment: @user2864740 eh, ok, what if it's `object`, see the edit.

Comment: The caller still needs to *specify* the T and this *needs* to be known at compile-time which is *before* the value of any object (including that which is supplied as an argument) is known. Since T *must* be specified it might as well be used as well.

Comment: Actually, forget object, I set up my edit to make it more realistic.  Also, is there a way to avoid having to convert or define this each time I return a list?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The caller **needs** to specify T at compile-time. This will determine the *actual* type of the return expression regardless of the source value(s).

Comment: Is there another way without using T?

Comment: Return a collection for a unified type - however the closest such gets to unification here is `List<object>`. The burden of type-refinement is *still* on the caller (there are various of ways of handling this, but the problem has just been "shifted").

Comment: Problem with using `object` i need to convert it everytime I want to view it as an int or string, etc.-- Gets to be tedious and shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to make a custom object on the fly? `new Object { int Id = 1, string Name = "name" };`?

Comment: @ControlFreak [`new { .. }`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), but it doesn't help here.

Comment: @ControlFreak Change return type of method to object, then it will work or else find out a way to define type T which is known at compile time, this is how generics work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return `IList` instead of `List<T>`. I have redefine your **ReturnList** and is now look like this -

```
public IList ReturnList(string key)
{
    //var type = Data[key].GetType().Name;
    switch (key)
    {
        case "System.Boolean":
            return new List<bool>(); break;
        case "System.Int32":
            return new List<int>(); break;
        case "System.String":
            return new List<string>(); break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I assume your dictionary contains value like this -

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"bool", typeof(bool)},
    {"string", typeof(string)},
    {"Int", typeof(int)}
};
```

You can modify your function as per your need.

I have tested it in **[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3bz4W)** console application like this -

```
var type = dict["bool"].ToString();
Program prg = new Program();
var list = prg.ReturnList(type);
Console.WriteLine(list);
```

Comment: This looks promising. So what's the benefit of using `IList` besides not having to define a type for it?  I'm assuming it consumes more processes than defining them?

Comment: @ControlFreak: `List<T>` is generic type in which the compile-time type needs to be known and `IList` is non-generic collection of objects. If you refer the MSDN for [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) you find that it has implemented `IList` i.e. is the base interface for lists. BTW sorry for the late reply...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit wierd question but i think this will d the trick:

```
public List<T> ReturnList<T>(string key){  
    if (Data[key].GetType() != typeof (T))
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid data type for key");
    }

    return new Lit<T>();
}
```

Still got the type check but using all the benefits of a generic method.

Comment: This would be nice and compact if it didn't require the `T` during usage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write **break** after return statement and **case** before default.
Also the name of bool type is "Boolean" and int is actually "Int32".

```
    public static IList ReturnList(string key)
    {  
        var type = Data[key].GetType().Name;
        switch(type){
        case "Boolean":            
            return new List<bool>();
        case "Int32":         
            return new List<int>();
        case "String": 
        default:
            return new List<string>();
        }   
        return null;
    }
```

Example:

```
        Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Data.Add("someBool", true);
        Data.Add("someInt", 42);
        Data.Add("someString","test");

        IList listString = ReturnList("someString");
        IList listInt = ReturnList("someInt");
        IList listBool = ReturnList("someString");
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, could say Javascript habits. However, since your answer is similar to the one above, what's the benefit of using IList besides not having to define a type for it? I'm assuming it consumes more processes than defining them?

Comment: @ControlFreak You don't exactly know what type ReturnList function will return, so instead of using [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) you could get an object of interface. I Hope this is helpful to you)